# Angular 1.3 form validation with deep objects as ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have a form that is using a scope var:

```
function Money() {
    this.notional = 0;
}
$scope.money = new Money();
```

but I am not sure how to display errors for this when it is invalid **myForm.money.notional**

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.money.notional" money="money" finance-input size="30" required
           placeholder="insert currency value"/>

    <div ng-if="myForm.money.notional.$invalid">
        There is an error with the field...
    </div>

        <pre>
Errors = {{ myForm.money.notional.$error  }}
    </pre>

    <button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
    <button ng-click="update(user)" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's validation infrastructure requires the *element* names, not the model names.

In your case, you have given a name to the form, but *not* to the `<input>`. So, if you change the HTML to:

```
<form name="myform">
    ...
    <input ... name="notional" />
```

You can test for validity as:

```
<div ng-if="myForm.notional.$invalid">...</div>
```